# Passing parent controller to modal (Angular-ui bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I feel like this should work, but it's not. I want to be able to pass the controller that is opening the modal so I can use its submit function etc. I am using the controllerAs pattern (so not using $scope).

```
var _this = this;

this.openModal = function(modalId,dataIn){
    this.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: modalId,
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'modal',
        resolve: {
            modalObject: function(){
                return dataIn;
            },
            title: function(){
                return 'Training Info';
            },
            parent: function(){
                return _this
            }
        }
    });

    _this.modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
        $log.log('submitting data for '+_this.doctorId);
        experienceFactory.submitTraining(data).then(function(){
            loadExperience();
        },function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, function () {
        //something on close
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};

this.something = function(){
    $log.warn('omg it workt?');
};
```

That is opened up with a simple `aCtrl.openModal('a-modal',aCtrl.data)` however for some reason I can't access the `parent` controller

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="a-modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{modal.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button ng-click="parent.something()">Something</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

The button does nothing, but should be printing the warnings. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't include the code of your controller, however I think that you misunderstood how dependencies are provided to the modal's controller.

The `resolve` part provides dependencies to the controller, it neither binds them to the scope nor to the controller. Take a look at this JS part of UI-Bootstrap's Modal example:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
    $scope.items = items;
```

In your case it should be

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', ['parent', function (parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
```

And in HTML, if you are using controllerAs pattern:

```
 <button ng-click="modal.parent.something()">Something</button>
```

Comment: Yes. This was the issue. I was just about to return here to post that. I ended up doing effectively what you're doing. Thanks.